# Search VSCode in subfolder, not the whole workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code

How can I search in one subfolder folder of my workspace only?

<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> searches in the whole workspace, and since this is large I get way too many hits in unrelated folders and files.

Comment: Right click on the folder -> Find in folder

Comment: @El Dude - please select an answer. The one that has 18 upvotes is the best, I believe.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Two options:

- Left-click the folder in the Explorer and use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>
- Right-click the folder in the Explorer and choose "Find in folder..."

This will give you a slightly changed search bar:

[image: vscode search in folders sidebar]

Answer (score 6):

The key combo is <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Answer (score 5):

Another twist on this is how to search in a collection of named subfolders.
For example, consider a directory structure like this:

```
Project
├── Foo
│   ├── inc
│   │   ├── tom.h
│   │   └── dick.h
│   └── src
│       ├── tom.cpp
|       └── dick.c
├── Bar
│   ├── inc
│   │   └── harry.h
│   └── src
│       └── harry.c
```

The "files to include" box will accept `glob` notation, so if the user wants to search only in "src" directories, not in "inc" directories, they can specify:

```
./**/src/*
```

This is interpreted (from right to left) as "any file, in a 'src' sub-directory, underneath any directory".

Obviously, this is a trivial example which could be handled by filtering on the file extension, but the principle applies to much more complex searches. For another example, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59083215/6419400

Answer (score 3):

There is a `...` under the search box:

[image: search in a specific folder]

After clicking on it, you can specify which files you want to include or exclude from your search results.

You can also use wildcards as shown in the placeholder.

For example, if I write this in the `files to include` field:

`repo/*.go`

then it will show you `all` files with `.go` extension in `repo` folder.

> star * means all

---

There is also two other ways to open this option (as Jeroen also mentioned):

- Right-click the folder in the Explorer and choose "Find in Folder..."
- Left-click the folder in the Explorer and use <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in windows or <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> in Mac