# Visual Studio Code Advanced Search Wildcard in Files to Include

Tags: visual-studio-code, glob

I am trying to find a line of code to all my files with a specific file name criteria. I am trying to take advantage the **Advanced Search** of the Visual Studio Code by putting a ***wildcard*** in the ***files to include*** field of the search. But I wasn't able to achieve that. I tried to use ***asterisk* (*)** symbol, but I think the Visual Studio Code does not accept that. So I tried to search the internet and found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46795624/2637261) by using the **.+?**; however, it still does nothing.

`Search Keyword`: **ICustomMatColumn**

`files to include`: ***(wildcard)viewmodel.ts***

[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Apparently, Visual Studio Code supports `glob syntax` which is really great. To achieve the desired result in the question, you just need to follow this format:

> ./**/*< partialFileName >

Example

**Folder Structure:**

```
|-- app
    |-- users
        |-- list.ts|html|css|viewmodel
        |-- form.ts|html|css|viewmodel
    |-- cars
        |-- list.ts|html|css|viewmodel
        |-- form.ts|html|css|viewmodel
        |-- configurator.ts|html|css|viewmodel
    |-- app.component.ts|html|css
    |-- app.module.ts
    |-- user.service.ts
    |-- car.service.ts
|-- index.html
|-- main.ts
|-- style.css
```

Let's Assume that every ViewModel file has this word/code/string **ICustomMatColumn**

> Search Keyword: **ICustomMatColumn**
>
> Files to Include: ./**/*ViewModel.ts

**Search Result:**

```
|-- app
    |-- users
        |-- list.ts|viewmodel
        |-- form.ts|viewmodel
    |-- cars
        |-- list.ts|viewmodel
        |-- form.ts|viewmodel
        |-- configurator.ts|viewmodel
```

It will strictly include only the files with the partialFileName that you entered in the ***files to include field***

Comment: Note: You can add this after a path like:
"./folderA/folderB/**/*ViewModel.ts"
Self-explanatory, but maybe the short example above is not understandable for everyone. ;)

Comment: Thanks. For `glob syntax` see => https://mincong.io/2019/04/16/glob-expression-understanding/

Comment: Extending on this answer: I wanted to search in a specific folder, and all of it's subfolders - limited by file extension.

some-folder/**/*.java

Answer (score 7):

So I found that the ***asterisk* (*)** works when you put in the ***files to include*** field the higher level folder name as the criteria

> The format will be **higherLevelFolderName***

Example:

**Folder Structure:**

```
|-- app
    |-- users
        |-- list.ts|html|css|viewmodel
        |-- form.ts|html|css|viewmodel
    |-- cars
        |-- list.ts|html|css|viewmodel
        |-- form.ts|html|css|viewmodel
        |-- configurator.ts|html|css|viewmodel
    |-- app.component.ts|html|css
    |-- app.module.ts
    |-- user.service.ts
    |-- car.service.ts
|-- index.html
|-- main.ts
|-- style.css
```

Let's Assume that every ViewModel file has this word/code/string **ICustomMatColumn**

> Search Keyword: **ICustomMatColumn**
>
> Files to Include: **app***

**Search Result:**

```
|-- app
    |-- users
        |-- list.ts|viewmodel
        |-- form.ts|viewmodel
    |-- cars
        |-- list.ts|viewmodel
        |-- form.ts|viewmodel
        |-- configurator.ts|viewmodel
```

But the **CONS** of this solution is in case your search criteria is present in the other file, it will be included to the search result.